# mrt:iron-router-progress not working with new meteor 1.0 update?

Tags: meteor

when i update meteor 0.9.4 to 1.0 it shows a message

> downgraded mrt:iron-router-progress from version 0.9.2 to version
>   0.4.0

this package also cause problem in client

> Uncaught ReferenceError: IronRouterProgress is not defined

what i can do to update it to ver 1.0 ?

[image]

Comment: some packages like `accunts-entry` and `accounts-template-core` are facing the same issues, better report in the github and wait for update or you can send pull request to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using below cammand from meteor 1.0

```
multiply:iron-router-progress
```